# Way to optimize Data Transfer between EBS to EFS

Tags: linux, database, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, rsync

We're trying to export the binary column data into an EFS file system mounted on the same Oracle instance. The total size is approximately 180 GB and have around 6 million files. I see that it's taking huge amount  of time (more than 30+hrs) to export directly to EFS mounted on the same host.

We also tried to export the column data on an EBS volume attached to the same instance and it took around 3:30 hrs but again transferring from EBS to EFS is taking same amount of time. Even zipping the objects and moving the zipped file over to EFS is not an option because we'll again have to unzip the file there and that will again take huge amount of time.

Could someone please recommend an another way to optimize the data transfer speed.

Comment: Did you create the EFS as General Purpose or Max I/O?

Comment: Tried both methods but no luck.

Comment: You make EFS faster by storing more data on it.  [Its sustainable throughput is based on how much is stored](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html), with throughput over time equal to about 50 MiB/s per TiB stored.